# Difference in meaning of sentences when will and would are used

Tags: grammar, tense, will-would

> I asked him when **he would** go there.

vs

> I asked him when **he will** go there.

Which one is correct? If both are correct, what is difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 2):

"I asked him when he would go there" is correct. When the verb in the main clause is in a past tense, "will" in the subordinate clause changes to "would":

> He *said* he **would** call me.
>
> I *explained* what I **would** do.
>
> I *asked* when the photos **would** be ready.
>
> I *was showing* how I **would** do that.
>
> The heating wan't working, so we *hoped* the engineer **wouldn't** take long.

That's how we express the future in the past.